# Unexpected "IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mappng found" thrown by Spring MVC in standalone tomcat

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I noticed a weird behavior in my Spring MVC application:

- My request mappings are all unique and I am positive there are no ambiguous mappings. **I can run my app fine in STS's embedded tomcat**.
- However when I drop a jar in a **standalone tomcat, I systematically get an ambiguous mapping error** as show below.

Stacktrace:

```
IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'preferenceController' bean method 
public java.lang.String com.bignibou.controller.PreferenceController.modifyEmail(com.bignibou.controller.helpers.EmailInfo,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model)
to {[/preferences/email],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/html],custom=[]}: There is already 'preferencesController' bean method
public java.lang.String com.bignibou.controller.PreferencesController.modifyEmail(com.bignibou.controller.helpers.EmailInfo,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,org.springframework.ui.Model) mapped.
```

Has anyone seen this problem before? FYI, I run tomcat 7.0.35 and spring 3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two different classes: `PreferenceController` and `PreferencesController` with the same method. Just delete one of the `modifyEmail` methods and see if it works.

Comment: Well spotted David! I actually renamed that class from PreferencesController to PreferenceController a while ago. I've mvn cleaned the app and the old class is still somewhere. Very odd...

Comment: Also just to be sure, you can delete everything in Tomcat's temporary directories: `rm -rf $CATALINA_HOME/work/*`